# JPA (Hibernate) Query returns no results with a valid query

Tags: hibernate, jpa, resultset

Environment is:

SQL Server 2008 running on W2K8 Datacenter Server,

Running on Mac OS X 10.6.8:
Hibernate (3), JPA Provider (1.0.1-Final),
Spring 3.0.6,
Java 6

The situation is that there is a particular object that I cannot retrieve a result set for.  Even the simplest of queries doesn't work and it seems to be limited to this particular Entity class (InvDetail).  I have logged the SQL being generated:

Hibernate:

```
select invdetail0_.invdetailid as invdetai1_28_, invdetail0_.description as                                       descript2_28_, invdetail0_.invid as invid28_, invdetail0_.qty as qty28_,     invdetail0_.unitprice as unitprice28_ from INV_DETAIL invdetail0_`
```

Here's the table creation script:

`CREATE TABLE [dbo].[INV_DETAIL](
    [INVID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [INVDETAILID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [QTY] [int] NOT NULL,
    [UNITPRICE] [smallmoney] NOT NULL,
    [DESCRIPTION] [varchar](100) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_INV_DETAIL] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [INVDETAILID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON, FILLFACTOR = 90) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]`

The Java class itself:

```
    @Entity
@NamedQueries({
  @NamedQuery(name = "InvDetail.findAll", query = "select o from InvDetail o"),
  @NamedQuery(name = "InvDetail.findByHeaderId", query = "SELECT o from InvDetail o WHERE o.invid = :invid")
})
@Table(name = "INV_DETAIL")
public class InvDetail extends SmartBeanItem<InvDetail> implements Serializable {
  @Column(name ="description", nullable = false)
  private String description;
  @Id
  @Column(name="invdetailid",nullable = false)
  private Integer invdetailid;
  @Column(name="invid",nullable = false)
  private Integer invid;
  @Column(name="qty",nullable = false)
  private Integer qty;
  @Column(name="unitprice",nullable = false)
  private BigDecimal unitprice;

  public InvDetail() {
  }

  public InvDetail(String description, Integer invdetailid, Integer invid,
                   Integer qty, BigDecimal unitprice) {
    this.description = description;
    this.invdetailid = invdetailid;
    this.invid = invid;
    this.qty = qty;
    this.unitprice = unitprice;
  }

  public String getDescription() {
    return description;
  }

  public void setDescription(String description) {
    this.description = description;
  }

  public Integer getInvdetailid() {
    return invdetailid;
  }

  public void setInvdetailid(Integer invdetailid) {
    this.invdetailid = invdetailid;
  }

  public Integer getInvid() {
    return invid;
  }

  public void setInvid(Integer invid) {
    this.invid = invid;
  }

  public Integer getQty() {
    return qty;
  }

  public void setQty(Integer qty) {
    this.qty = qty;
  }

  public BigDecimal getUnitprice() {
    return unitprice;
  }

  public void setUnitprice(BigDecimal unitprice) {
    this.unitprice = unitprice;
  }
}
```

My persistence.xml:

```
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence
http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd"
version="2.0">
    <persistence-unit name="imUnit" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        ...
        <class>com.stuff.portal.portlet.model.ejb.InvHeader</class>
        <class>com.stuff.portal.portlet.model.ejb.InvDetail</class>
        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />
            <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="false" />
            <property name="hibernate.jdbc.batch_size" value="100" />
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
```

I have tried criteria queries (our standard way of performing queries) and they do not work.  So I tried to simplify and move to a named query, the following example returns no results:

```
TypedQuery<InvDetail> q = em.createNamedQuery("InvDetail.findAll", InvDetail.class);
// q.setParameter("invid", invid);
List<InvDetail> result = q.getResultList();
```

The data *is* in the database and when I run the SQL as generated by hibernate directly against the database, I get the results I expect.  As far as I can see, the logs indicate nothing wrong and if there was a problem with the transactions or the database, I would expect an exception to be thrown.

Here's my log:

```
DEBUG [http-8080-6] (JpaTransactionManager.java:355) - Exposing JPA transaction as JDBC transaction [org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect$HibernateConnectionHandle@23b76287]
DEBUG [http-8080-6] (ExtendedEntityManagerCreator.java:423) - Starting resource local transaction on application-managed EntityManager [org.hibernate.ejb.EntityManagerImpl@37975a46]
DEBUG [http-8080-6] (ExtendedEntityManagerCreator.java:400) - Joined local transaction
DEBUG [http-8080-6] (ExtendedEntityManagerCreator.java:400) - Joined local transaction
Hibernate: select invheader0_.invid as invid27_, invheader0_.exchangerate as exchange2_27_, invheader0_.incotermlocation as incoterm3_27_, invheader0_.incotermsid as incoterm4_27_, invheader0_.invcurrencyid as invcurre5_27_, invheader0_.invno as invno27_, invheader0_.invoicedate as invoiced7_27_, invheader0_.orgid as orgid27_, invheader0_.paymentstatusid as payments9_27_, invheader0_.paymenttermid as payment10_27_, invheader0_.paymentterms as payment11_27_, invheader0_.revisionnumber as revisio12_27_, invheader0_.supplierid as supplierid27_, invheader0_.surcharge as surcharge27_, invheader0_.tax as tax27_ from INV_HEADER invheader0_ where 1=1
DEBUG [http-8080-6] (AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:752) - Initiating transaction commit
DEBUG [http-8080-6] (JpaTransactionManager.java:462) - Committing JPA transaction on EntityManager [org.hibernate.ejb.EntityManagerImpl@79ae52b2]
DEBUG [http-8080-6] (JpaTransactionManager.java:548) - Closing JPA EntityManager [org.hibernate.ejb.EntityManagerImpl@79ae52b2] after transaction
DEBUG [http-8080-6] (EntityManagerFactoryUtils.java:328) - Closing JPA EntityManager
DEBUG [http-8080-6] (AbstractBeanFactory.java:244) - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'inventoryManagerTransactionManager'
DEBUG [http-8080-6] (AbstractBeanFactory.java:244) - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'liferayTransactionManager'
DEBUG [http-8080-6] (AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:365) - Creating new transaction with name [com.stuff.portal.portlet.service.impl.InventoryManagerServiceImpl.getDetailsForInvoice]: PROPAGATION_NESTED,ISOLATION_DEFAULT; 'inventoryManagerTransactionManager'
DEBUG [http-8080-6] (JpaTransactionManager.java:323) - Opened new EntityManager [org.hibernate.ejb.EntityManagerImpl@50b97081] for JPA transaction
DEBUG [http-8080-6] (JpaTransactionManager.java:355) - Exposing JPA transaction as JDBC transaction [org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect$HibernateConnectionHandle@3e894e8e]
DEBUG [http-8080-6] (ExtendedEntityManagerCreator.java:423) - Starting resource local transaction on application-managed EntityManager [org.hibernate.ejb.EntityManagerImpl@37975a46]
DEBUG [http-8080-6] (ExtendedEntityManagerCreator.java:400) - Joined local transaction
22:38:51,519 WARN  [ThemeLocalServiceImpl:121] No theme found for specified theme id clear_WAR_cleartheme. Returning the default theme.
22:38:51,521 WARN  [ThemeLocalServiceImpl:121] No theme found for specified theme id clear_WAR_cleartheme. Returning the default theme.
Hibernate: select invdetail0_.invdetailid as invdetai1_28_, invdetail0_.description as descript2_28_, invdetail0_.invid as invid28_, invdetail0_.qty as qty28_, invdetail0_.unitprice as unitprice28_ from INV_DETAIL invdetail0_
DEBUG [http-8080-6] (AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:752) - Initiating transaction commit
DEBUG [http-8080-6] (JpaTransactionManager.java:462) - Committing JPA transaction on EntityManager [org.hibernate.ejb.EntityManagerImpl@50b97081]
DEBUG [http-8080-6] (JpaTransactionManager.java:548) - Closing JPA EntityManager [org.hibernate.ejb.EntityManagerImpl@50b97081] after transaction
DEBUG [http-8080-6] (EntityManagerFactoryUtils.java:328) - Closing JPA EntityManager
```

Now what's interesting to note, if you take a look at the log, there is a different query to retrieve some InvHeader entities.  That query works perfectly fine, and subsequently I attempt to get InvDetail ... to no avail.  This only seems to be happening with InvDetail, all other objects in the system seem to be able to be queried with no issue.

I am at a loss as how to troubleshoot this further.  I have turned on what I think is all the appropriate logging and am finding nothing that sheds light on why 0 results are being returned when I'm asking for everything in the table.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: My guess is that the application doesn't use the database or schema you think it uses. Check the configuration of your data source / connection pool. Or the data is in the database, but not committed yet.

Comment: I've been down that path as well.  There's only one schema and I've checked the connection string.  The data is retrieved from other tables... just not the INV_DETAIL table all using the same data source.  The data is definitely in the database as it was inserted manually.

Comment: Actually JB, you were dead on.  I took a closer look and it seems that at some point the INV_DETAIL table was also created under a different schema (user).  This was causing the query to look at the wrong table.  ... Funny how sometimes the things that you spend the most time on are the easiest issues to resolve.  Thanks for the clarity!